# Postgresql Many to Many size optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, optimization, activerecord, many-to-many

As I was looking at my DB on my project, I realized that the heaviest table I have is a relationship table between two other tables.

A table integration, user and the famous integration_customers (linking user to integration).

- My User table size is: 2011 rows for 819kb (395kb data + 425kb indexes)
- My Integration table size is: 3 rows for 32kb (16kb data + 16kb indexes)
- My Integration Customers table size is: 2011 rows for 4Mb (4Mb data + 294kb indexes)

Here is the structure of this Integration Customers table:

```
1   "id"    "int4"  "NO"    NULL    "nextval('integration_customers_id_seq'::regclass)" ""  NULL
2   "user_id"   "int4"  "NO"    NULL    NULL    ""  NULL
3   "integration_id"    "int4"  "NO"    NULL    NULL    ""  NULL
4   "created_at"    "timestamp" "NO"    NULL    NULL    ""  NULL
5   "updated_at"    "timestamp" "NO"    NULL    NULL    ""  NULL
6   "parameters"    "jsonb" "YES"   NULL    "'{}'::jsonb"   ""  NULL
7   "marketing_info_email"  "bool"  "YES"   NULL    "true"  ""  NULL
8   "subscriber_id" "varchar"   "YES"   NULL    NULL    ""  NULL
```

And my indexes are:

```
"integration_customers_pkey"    "BTREE" t   "id"    ""  NULL
"index_integration_customers_on_user_id_and_integration_id" "BTREE" t   "user_id,integration_id"    ""  NULL
"index_integration_customers_on_user_id"    "BTREE" f   "user_id"   ""  NULL
"index_integration_customers_on_integration_id" "BTREE" f   "integration_id"    ""  NULL
```

I just find the size difference between the relationship table and the two others huge and I was wondering if I was missing something in the architecture or if it was normal? 
If this is abnormal, what did I do wrong?
If it is normal, is there a way to optimize it?

Happy to provide more information if needed :)

Thank you all very much for your time!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly is the "issue"? Is it just that you don't like the scale of the table size differences? Or, are you experiencing a performance issue of some kind?

Comment: @jvillian
The "issue" (because I don't even know if this is one) is the size of this relationship table. Why is it SO big compared to the others? And is there a way to reduce its size? If so, how?

Comment: So, maybe your question should be whether it is in fact an issue. Maybe it's not.

Comment: @jvillian Done! Is it better? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the size is just what you have to expect because the table contains more data. Remember that an m-to-n relationship table can easily have more entries than the referenced tables.

Maybe the table is bloated. Install the `pgstattuple` extension and use the function with the same name on the table to find out if that is the case. If yes, schedule a `VACUUM (FULL)` and tune autovacuum to be more aggressive.

Comment: You are probably very right. I wouldn't have imagined that such a schema would create a heavy table compare to the others.

I ran `pgstattuple` on my development table but I am not sure of what I am supposed to see from it. To me it looks like the vacuum wouldn't do much in this case since there is no dead tuple, am I interpreting it right?

"table_len": 4145152,
"tuple_count": 2011,
"tuple_len": 114627,
"tuple_percent": 2.77,
"dead_tuple_count": 0,
"dead_tuple_len": 0,
"dead_tuple_percent": 0,
"free_space": 3978116,
"free_percent": 95.97
Thank you for your help!

Comment: That means that your table is horribly bloated. There are only 2011 rows in it, and 96% of the space is empty. You must run `VACUUM (FULL)` on it. Then lower `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much for this!
I found a good piece of documentation about vacuuming on Heroku, it will definitely help!